# (VC 2019) C++ return statement ignored in release configuration, works fine in debug

Tags: c++, function, return, visual-studio-debugging

I have this simple piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool sequence_increase(std::vector<int>& sequence, const int& index) {
    if (index >= sequence.size()) return true;
    if (sequence[sequence.size() - index - 1] < 2 * index) {
        sequence[sequence.size() - index - 1]++;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (index == sequence.size() - 1) return true;
        else {
            sequence[sequence.size() - index - 1] = 0;
            sequence_increase(sequence, index + 1);
        }
    }
}

void pairing(std::vector<int> list, const std::vector<int>& sequence) {
    std::vector<int> list_copy;
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++) {
        int a, b; a = list[0];
        list.erase(list.begin());
        b = list[sequence[i]];
        list.erase(list.begin() + sequence[i]);
        std::cout << "(" << a << ", " << b << ")";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void pairings(const int& n) {
    std::vector<int> list(2*n);
    std::vector<int> seq; seq.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) list[i] = i + 1;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        int index = 0;
        std::cout << "sequence: ";
        for (auto& s : seq) std::cout << s << " "; std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "pairing: ";
        pairing(list, seq);
        quit = sequence_increase(seq, index);
        std::cout << "quit? " << quit << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    pairings(2);
}
```

To explain, I wanted to generate all pairings of a list of $2n$ elements, such as

```
(12)(34)
(13)(24)
(14)(23)
```

The mapping takes in sequence of $n$ numbers, where number on position $n-k$ only goes up to $2k-1$ (or, as in my code, from 0 to $2k-2$). This sequence of numbers is then translated into a unique pairing in the function void pairing, and as far as I know, this works fine.

To generate all possible combinations in the sequence I helped myself with the function bool sequence_increase, that takes a general sequence and increases it by 1

```
320 -> 400
```

(here 0 at the end is already at its maximum value, as well as 2 before, so it zeroes them out and increases 3 to 4)

The sequence goes like

```
000
010
020
100
110
120
200
..
```

(longer sequences are analogous)

To know when to stop is when the intended increase position goes out of bounds, which is ensured one step earlier by `if (index == sequence.size() - 1) return true;` in the function `sequence_increase` which indicates that it cannot increase any more. This gets stored in the variable quit in the function pairings and this should halt the `while(!quit)` loop.

Here's the issue: the program works fine on debug mode (VC 2019), here's some last of the succesful outputs:
[image]

as you can see, the routine returned true which ended the while loop and the program ended.

However, in release mode, the routine sequence_increase never returns true, so it never ends
[image]

I can't wrap my head around it. What could be the cause? How can I make this work on release configuration? Thanks.

Comment: "*What could be the cause?*" - undefined behavior could be the cause. For example, not all paths in `bool sequence_increase()` return a `bool` value.

Comment: You need to return the result of the recursive call: `return sequence_increase(sequence, index + 1);`

Comment: turn on your compilers warnings, gcc has a lot to tell about your code: https://godbolt.org/z/P7Mbn6 (the last one is the most interesting one)

Comment: or better yet, treat them as errors https://godbolt.org/z/oo5eoE

Comment: BTW, VC 2019 reports the issue with default settings. https://godbolt.org/z/PM194r

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yep, this is exactly right, thanks!

Comment: @idclev463035818 that's a very good resource! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have never return a value under

```
 else
 {
         sequence[sequence.size() - index - 1] = 0;
         sequence_increase(sequence, index + 1);
 }
```

**Since** Release mode performs a logical process under that, you have to return `sequence_increase(sequence, index + 1);` just as **Johnny Mopp** said(thanks to him for sharing the tip) to end the loop to return true.

**Suggestion**

So change to use this:

```
bool sequence_increase(std::vector<int>& sequence, const int& index) {
    if (index >= sequence.size()) return true;
    if (sequence[sequence.size() - index - 1] < 2 * index) {
        sequence[sequence.size() - index - 1]++;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (index == sequence.size() - 1) return true;
        else {
            sequence[sequence.size() - index - 1] = 0;
            sequence_increase(sequence, index + 1);
            return sequence_increase(sequence, index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. In this context, it sufficed to rewrite the part into
else {
        sequence[sequence.size() - index - 1] = 0;
        return sequence_increase(sequence, index + 1);
    }

Comment: `index == sequence.size() - 1` triggers a warning, and it will cause problems when `sequence` has no elements (but in that case anyhow the lines above will already have UB)